# Change listview header and item background

Tags: android, android-listview, android-theme

I'm working on a custom theme for my app. Currrently all the listviews are using the same drawable for listview header background, and two alternating drawables for listview item background to achieve alternating light/dark list items.

I was wondering if these 3 drawables could be changed/replaced for every custome theme i do. But i'm not sure how to go about it. Any help or input? Thank you in advance

Just in case:

I set the drawable for list header background in android:background attr inside listview_headr.xml (which i inflate into say header_view and do list.addHeaderView(header_view).

As for list item background i use setBackgroundResource in the respective adapter used to populate the list by overriding getView method

Answer (score 0):

You can apply different theme to list view and in each theme you can set different drawables.